# How do I print from an application to a line printer in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, printer, filenames

I'm using Linux Mint and I have a BASIC interpreter that normally sends the output of LPRINT, LLIST, etc. to /dev/null. I want to send it to the line printer (network connected). BASIC has a command line option:
BAS --lp *filename*
This is supposed to send the output to a file. It works to send it to a disk file but I want to send it to the printer file instead. I tried
BAS --lp //192.168.1.129:9100
but this creates a text file in the root called 192.168.1.129:9100
LP and LPR work fine but I can't use them to redirect BASIC's printer output to the printer. I need a file name for the printer.
Any ideas?

Comment: Never used this, but I wonder if the --lp parameter should be a resource - like 'socket://192.168.1.129:9100'   (Note the single quotes)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I get

bas: Opening `socket://192.168.1.129:9100' for line printer output failed (No such file or directory).

I know the IP address of the printer is 192.168.1.129. How does CUPS see it?